# Python 3.5.2 loading data from internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

First off this is not homework, it is for self learning, I am a graduate student.
I'm new to Python and matplotlib and I'm trying to give myself a crash course because I'm going to need matplotlib to plot some of my own work pretty soon. I'm currently trying to learn a bit about both by following some Youtube tutorials and I seem to have gotten stuck. I need to figure out why this code won't run for me because I need it to move on in the rest of the tutorials.

This code has been copied directly from the tutorial I'm following but it fails for me, yet works for the creator of the videos. I've re-checked the syntax countless times against the one in the video, and also tried some of the solutions that worked for people having similar problems in the comments section.

It seems the differences come from peoples versions of python. Mine is currently Python 3.5.2. 
The code is supposed to pull stock data from the web, convert the time to a python friendly format and then graph it.
Does anybody have any idea how to get this going for my python version so I can continue my original objective to learn about plotting?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

def graph_data(stock):
    stock_price_url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/*instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=10y/csv'
    source_code = urllib.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
    stock_data = []
    split_source = source_code.split('\n')
    for line in split_source:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        if len(split_line) == 6:
            if 'values' not in line:
                stock_data.append(line)

    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_data, delimiter =',', unpack=True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})

    plt.plot_date(date, closep)

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Load from file\nInteresting graph')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    graph_data('TSLA')
```

Which produces the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "load_from_internet.py", line 35, in <module>
        graph_data('TSLA')
     File "load_from_internet.py", line 16, in graph_data
        source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

    AttributeError: module'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Examples of attempt to fix problem:

changing import urllib to

```
   import urllib.request
```

This small change has apparently worked for others with different versions of Python but not for me. I get a different error with urlib.request:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "load_from_internet.py", line 35, in <module>
        graph_data('TSLA')
     File "load_from_internet.py", line 16, in graph_data
        source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()

     File "C:\Users\myfiles\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    File "C:\Users\myfiles\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    File "C:\Users\myfiles\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response

    File "C:\Users\myfiles\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain

      File "C:\Users\myfiles\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
            raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
        urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

P.S the whole point of the tutorial is to pull stock data from the internet and plot it, and then further tutorials are for customising the graph it produces (Which is what I want to learn). The date conversion is more of an aside, and the tutor says that if you don't understand what is going on with the conversion that's fine for now - but the problem is that not understanding what is going on with the conversion is why I'm not able to fix it!
So any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: *"code won't run"*, *"it fails for me"*  So what happens?  Do you get an error?  If so, please show the *complete* error message.  Does it generate an unexpected result?  If so, show or explain the result, and explain what you expected.

Comment: You are saying you changed `import urllib` to `import urllib.request`, but also that you changed `urllib.request.urlopen` to `urllib.urlopen` in the code. Is that a mistake in the copy-pasting? Also, if the code fails, *what error* do you get, or what happens instead of the expected outcome?

Comment: As I said I'm new to Python and I can't see the error for some reason either. When I double click my script to run it, the prompt opens for a moment and then closes too quickly for me to be able to read any error. So yes "it fails for me". If I'd have been able to see the error, I would have posted it. It generates no result at all. I've been plotting data from files until now with no problems. The result should be a graph with the dates on x axis and the closing stock price on y axis. The prompt/error screen opens for a split second, not long enough to read the error and closes again.

Comment: Run your script in the terminal. That is, open a console window, navigate to the path of your script and type `python nameofscript.py`. In this way you'll get the error message.

Comment: I should add that in the other scripts I've been running, I run them by just double clicking on the script. The (empty) py.exe window opens along with my graph and stays open. When there's a problem with the code, the py.exe just kind of pops up for long enough to realise there's an error message on it and then it disappears.

Comment: I'm getting the following AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen' for line 16 (the source_code line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in a notebook.

1 - replace the import statement with

```
import six.moves.urllib as url
```

2 - use the alias to call urlopen method

```
source_code = url.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
```

3 - remove all the white spaces at the beginning of the last line

```
graph_data('TSLA')
```

As it is written, the method call is within the method itself, hence never call.

Moreover the Url is malformed and generate an HTTP 404 Content not found error. In HTTP, request parameters are delimited using "&", not ";".

Just changing all ; with & doesn't fix the issue however, so there is also an error in the API call. This looks like an old tutorial, the yahoo Api is not like this anymore.

Have a look over here, it's a bit involved, but this is exactly what your are looking for:

https://www.udacity.com/course/machine-learning-for-trading--ud501

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that!

Comment: Well the date the video was posted was July 2015, so it doesn't seem to be so old. Quite irritating though as the rest of the tutorials for customising the graphs are on the basis of this one script with this data set.

Comment: I actually got it working with your suggestion for changing urllib, thank you very much! For completeness I'd like to add that I also had to remove the '*' in the url line : stock_price_url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/*instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=10y/csv' which I had added because of a suggestion by someone that their antivirus might be causing the error (I was pretty much trying any suggestion!), however even with removing that the code did not work until I corrected the urllib import.